# AlpineJs change x-data according to select

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I use

```php
x-data="{tab: 'option1'}"
```

and need to change tab according to dropdown selection.
how to do this with alpinejs? @click did not work

```php
 <select>
      <option @click="tab = 'tab1'">{{ __('option1') }}</option>
      <option @click="tab = 'tab2'">{{ __('option2') }}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`x-model`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model#select-inputs) attribute to bind a variable to the select element.

```
<div x-data="{tab: 'option1'}">
  <select x-model="tab">
    <option value="option1">{{ __('option1') }}</option>
    <option value="option2">{{ __('option2') }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The `tab` variable will receive the value of the selected option.